# Change layout of transactional emails not pdf

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to change the design/ text/ fonts  of the transactional emails, do I need to change it in code and if so what files do I need to look at and any other advice in doing it

please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the email design, appearance, content, etc you need to work with the template files. They are located in the `app/locale` folder, under the language you are using. So, for en_US, for example, they would be at `app/locale/en_US/template/email`.

You can edit the template's html directly, and specify a css file using a template directive - the double curly braces syntax ex: `{{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}` would reference `skin/frontend/base/default/css/email-inline.css`

Depending on what you need in the emails you may need to add custom template directives. There is an article on that [here](http://www.envalo.com/creating-custom-email-template-directives/).